# Github: не могу выложить из за ошибки LF , CRLF

Tags: github

Недавно начал изучать GitHub, столкнулся с такой проблемой:
директория есть, файл там лежит, мои действия (как я выкладывал) на картинке.
Файл сделал с помощью notepad++.

> fatal: pathspec did not match any files

Что это?

[image: gitProblem]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в окончании файла. На Win и Linux они различны.

Использовать что-то типо [dos2unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068179/convert-line-endlings-for-whole-directory-tree-git/7068241#7068241) или [Swiss File Knife](http://stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=remcrlf) для преобразования, чтоб ошибка исчезла.

Или попробовать что-то такое:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

Answer (score 2):

Это можно исправить командой

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

или

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

но лучшим вариантом, будет разобраться с этим в документациях, потому, что это не лучший выход из ситуации.